# Geometric distribution and entropy

Tags: inference, entropy, information-theory, density-estimation, maximum-entropy

According to wikipedia, among all discrete probability distributions supported on $\{1, 2, 3, ... \}$ with given expected value $\mu$, the geometric distribution X with parameter $p = \frac{1}{
\mu} $ is the one with the largest entropy.

What does it mean for applications? Is the following way of thinking correct?

Assume we have got some count data and the data and frequency estimator looks like decreasing. Then, if nothing else is known, then, according to the Principle of maximum entropy, we first try to fit the data by geometric distribution.

Comment: Did you find this on Wikipedia [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_maximum_entropy#Testable_information)?

Comment: yes, I read this article.

Comment: Why doesn't that article answer your question? What is your question exactly? **1** Do you ask for an explanation about the principle of maximum entropy or **2** do you ask whether the principle of maximum entropy is correctly applied?

Comment: actually, I was asking both these questions.

Comment: Something else that confuses me as well: What do you mean by *"try to fit the data by geometric distribution"*?

Comment: The reaskn for my earlier post was because it is not so clear to me what your question asks for. You start with *"According to Wikipedia..."* is what follows something unclear (whether the geometric distribution is the maximum entropy distribution for probability distribution on discrete positive numbers)? Or is there something else? Could you explain better what the problem is.